# bind to a property in the parent control

Tags: wpf, xaml

i have the following case:

```
Window
  |_Grid
      |_ListView (MainProductGrid)
           |_View
               |_GridView
                    |_GridViewColumn
                             |_CellTemplate
                                     |_DataTemplate
                                             |_Label (LabelID)
```

now, i want to display in the LabelID the index of the row in the ListView.
so i made the following:

```
<ListView ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductItems}" AlternationCount="{Binding Path=ProductItems.Count}">
...
```

and for the label i have the following:

```
<Label x:Name="LabelID" 
       Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=TemplatedParent}, 
       Path=(ListView.AlternationIndex)}"/>
```

but it LabelID is only showing 0..
so i think the TemplatedParent is not pointing to the ListView control..
so how can i correct the binding to point to the "upper parent" which is in my case the ListView ?

thanks in advance

################

Update: 
here is the complete xaml ...

```
<Grid x:Name="mainGrid">
        <ListView  ItemsSource="{Binding Path=ProductItems}" AlternationCount="{Binding Path=ProductItems.Count}" x:Name="MainProductGrid">
                <ListView.View>
                    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
                    <GridViewColumn x:Name="gvc" Header="id" Width="auto">
                        <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <Label Content="{Binding (ListView.AlternationIndex),RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                    </GridViewColumn>

                    <GridViewColumn Header="Product name" DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProductName}"  Width="auto" />
                    </GridView>
                </ListView.View>
            </ListView>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Please try:

```
<Label Content="{Binding (ListView.AlternationIndex),
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"  />
```

Update:
Here is the correct xaml, the binding should be set to `RelativeSource=ListViewItem`, yet there was a problem with the grid column width:

```
<ListView.View>
    <GridView AllowsColumnReorder="False">
        <GridViewColumn x:Name="gvc" Header="id"  Width="30">
            <GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding (ListView.AlternationIndex),
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor,
                            AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"/>
                </DataTemplate>
            </GridViewColumn.CellTemplate>
        </GridViewColumn>

        <GridViewColumn Header="Product name"
                        DisplayMemberBinding="{Binding Path=ProductName}"
                        Width="auto" />
    </GridView>
</ListView.View>
```

Comment: no, didnt work ...cant see how it would work if iam looking in the ListViewItem instead the ListView itself !??

Comment: edited my answer, worked for me! you should refer to the item because you want each item index

Comment: thanks for your posting..i will test it tomorrow and will let you know if it works ..cheers

Comment: {Binding Path=AlternationIndex, RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListViewItem}}}"

Answer (score 5):

You can use

```
RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}
```

to find a specific control above you

Comment: i also tried pointing to the listview using ElementName and üath, but also didnt work ..

Answer (score 2):

Well since you're in the context of a `DataTemplate` you cannot access the property via `TemplatedParent` mode, at least in your case. It *refers to the element to which the template (in which the data-bound element exists) is applied. [...]* [Link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.windows.data.relativesourcemode.aspx) I'm not sure, that it can be used in a `DataTemplate` because I've only seen it in `ControlTemplates`, but since the docs are not telling otherwise...

What you can do is to try find the `Ancestor`. E.g.

```
<Label Content="{Binding AlternationIndex, 
       RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type ListView}}" ... />
```

I didn't used in `DataTemplates` yet, so no warranty.